# Imitating ls in ansi C

Tags: c, linux, ls

I have a code to mimic **ls -la** in ansi C, but when I change the directory from . (current directory) to any other it keep saying No such file or directory, any ideas why?

code:

```
DIR * mydir;
struct dirent * mydirent;
struct stat st;
char outstr[100];
struct tm *tmp;
mydir = opendir("..");
while ((mydirent=readdir(mydir))!=NULL)
  if ( stat(mydirent->d_name,&st) != -1 ) {
    tmp = localtime(&st.st_mtime);
    if (tmp == NULL)
      perror("localtime ERROR: ");
    else {
      strftime(outstr, sizeof(outstr), "%d/%m/%Y", tmp);
      printf("%o\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%s\t%s\n",
    st.st_mode, st.st_nlink, st.st_uid, st.st_gid, 
    st.st_size, outstr, mydirent->d_name);
    }
  } 
  else 
    perror("stat ERROR: ");
closedir(mydir);
```

Comment: Did you consider using a debugger?

Comment: your title is misleading, your question has nothing to do with a particular version of C that you are using. "Re-implementing POSIX ls" or so would be better, I think.

Comment: @JensGustedt: It _is_ ANSI C... We are used to stating c++03, c89, c99, c++0x all the time here to avoid confusion

Comment: opendir("..") opens the parent directory. Didn't you want (".") for the current directory?

Comment: Thanks for the answers =) cnicutar was right I was forgeting to add the fullpath, sorry for troubles and thanks @sehe for the clarification

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to concatenate the directory path and the file name.

```
stat(mydirent->d_name,&st) /* d_name is just the name, not the full path. */
```

Use `s(n)printf` or something like that:

```
sprintf(fullpath, "%s/%s", dirpath, mydirent->d_name);
stat(fullpath, &st);
```

Comment: thanks, didn't see it =) it's always great when a fresh pair of eyes watch your own code because =)

Comment: I have one more question if you have the time and the kindness ... do you know how can I differ files from folders?

Comment: @Saikios `S_ISDIR(mydirent->st_mode);`

Comment: thanks, for the hint =) it works like this =) if(S_ISDIR(st.st_mode)) printf("I'm a directory");

IOU two answer on something now :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, as already stated by @cnicutar, that `stat` wants the filename in the form `dir/file`. The problems are:

- The `/` may not work on every operating system.
- You need to allocate memory for the composed string, do overflow checks ...

If you don't insist on ANSI and can live with POSIX instead, then you can try `fstatat` and `dirfd`:

```
int dirfd(DIR *dirp);    // convert DIR * from opendir() to dirhandle
int fstatat(int dirfd, const char *pathname, struct stat *buf, int flags);
```

With `fstatat` the `pathname` is relative to the directory handle and you can point `pathname` directly to `struct dirent.d_name`.